# Google Script to set formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to make a slight adjustment to a Google Sheets script, but I'm stuck, because of my inexperience. I know it's easier for you to help if you have background, so excuse me if I overdo it, just wanna make it easier for you if you have a good picture of what I need.

**Background...**
The sheets based project I'm tinkering with runs slowly, and I'm trying to make some alterations and improvements to filters etc so I can delete several deadwood unnecessary sheets in the workbook, which are currently used for directing info to the main info page.

I need to filter selected rows and columns from 'ALL' to five other sheets, which we are used to collate customers booking info, and are then faxed or emailed off to the relevant departments. Each of the five sheets has daily bookings for six months of the year, and I need to get a formula into a specific cells, one cell relating to each day of the year.

To do this manually would take forever, with 1,825 formulas to edit, and enter manually.

The current script works fine, I need to change and add one further filter condition to the formula which I want to set. Here's the current script...

```
function setFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
    sheet.getRange(4 + 26*k, 3).setFormula('=FILTER(MERQ!A:J, MERQ!D:D=date(2016,8,8)+' + k + ')');
  }
}
```

It's fine in that it sets the filter formula in C4, and every 26th cell below it, and each time it sets the formula in the cell below, the exact date filter condition increases by 1 day. EG...

In 'MER'C4 formula is

```
=FILTER(MERQ!A:J, MERQ!D:D=date(2016,6,15)+0)
```

In 'MER'C30...

```
=FILTER(MERQ!A:J, MERQ!D:D=date(2016,6,15)+1)
```

In 'MER'C56...

```
=FILTER(MERQ!A:J, MERQ!D:D=date(2016,6,15)+2)
```

And so on for a couple hundred times per sheet every 26th cell in column C. But, I want to change it to cut out 'MERQ", and add a filter condition.

I need to change the sheet from MERQ to ALL, that's not an issue, the dates in ALL are now in column H, also not a problem, the struggle I'm having is adding another filter condition...

```
H2:H="MER",
```

to the 3.setFormula line of the script, which if adjusted to the new sheet would read like below, before adding the additional filter condition above... ...

```
('=FILTER(ALL!D:M, ALL!G:G=date(2016,8,8)+' + k + ')');
```

The link to view the sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xh74Iex2HYuobEZp01bnY1R66DfoJDp2xB-kuA7xnF0/edit?usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Looks simple lile `('=FILTER(ALL!D:M, ALL!G:G=date(2016,8,8)+' + k + ', ALL!H2:H="MER")');`

Comment: Thanks Max. It works in as far as putting the formulas into the correct cells, but, it's not bring any values in from ALL as it should do. I've looked at the ranges and it looks good to me, so I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorted now, mismatched rows, D2 and G2, and it's all good. Thanks!